# Order of formula calculation in Excel 2016

Tags: excel

I would like to use the result of a formula A in another cell that is a part of the formula A and avoid circular reference. Also, iterative calculation doesn't sound like what I need.

Lets say I have a table with a single column of which each cell uses a formula that evaluates the state of the whole table and it does so from the top most cell to the bottom.

For example, formula is `=XXX+SUM($A$1:$A$4)` where `XXX` is the content of each cell and the table looks like this initially:

```
    A
    --
1 | 3
2 | 5
3 | 1
4 | 6
```

Lets say I have a trigger for calculation start and the first cell starts calculation:

A1 is now 3 + (3+5+1+6) = 18

after that A2 starts calculation and A2 is now 5 + (**18** + 5 + 1 + 6) = 35

after that A3 starts calculation and A3 is now 1 + (**18** + **35** + 1 + 6) = 61

after that A4 starts calculation and A3 is now 6 + (**18** + **35** + **61** + 6) = 126

So the final table would look like this:

```
    A
    --
1 | 18
2 | 35
3 | 61
4 | 126
```

Please understand that this is a simplified example, I am aware this calculation can be optimized but that is not what I need.

Is there a way to avoid VBA?

Comment: This will require vba.

Comment: You could probably do messily it using multiple helper columns but not in a single column formula. IMHO an array UDF would be the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

Only VBA will allow you to avoid hitting the circular reference problem.

If you are prepared to separate your output from your input then you can use Excel to replicate the calculation steps or with a bit of analysis you can simplify the calculation steps (though I suspect this is what you term as optimizing). Picture below shows both

[image]